# Determinant of a matrix for non-commutative products

Tags: matrices, determinant, noncommutative-algebra

Let's suppose we have a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ whose elements $a_{ij}$ are objects whose product is not commutative: $a_{ij}·a_{kl}\neq a_{kl}·a_{ij}$. Then, which would be the formula for the determinant $|A|$?

Answer (score 2):

In general, for a square matrix of dimension $n$ with coefficients in a ring $\mathcal A$, the determinant is given by:

$$\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n} \epsilon(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i),i}$$

so you can apply that to the case $n=3$. Now take care that several properties of determinants may not be true anymore if the ring $\mathcal A$ is not commutative! You can have a look at [quasideterminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasideterminant).

Comment: Ok, could you please develop a little more that expression? Not sure about the meaning of $\mathfrak S, \sigma$ and $\epsilon$...

Comment: Have a look at [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) where the formula is applied for the case $n=3$.

Comment: You meant this expression? $|A|=a_{11} a_{22} a_{33}+a_{12} a_{23} a_{31}+a_{13} a_{21} a_{32}-a_{13} a_{22} a_{31}-a_{12} a_{21} a_{33}-a_{11} a_{23} a_{32}$

Comment: Exactly that!!!